# Which file is responsible for Email template variables in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php

We need to update the email template variables in transaction emails in Magento, I don't know which model is responsible for this. Can you please help us to know this file?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the email that you want to send and the variable that you need, for exemple for the `sales order email` the function responsible is `sendNewOrderEmail()`located in :  `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` and if you want to add some params in your case variable, you should rewrite this file in local (it's forbidden to update the core Magento files) I think you already know.

**Solution 1: (Model)**

So i'll give an exemple to well understand how to add your custom variable.

For the **new order emai**l template:

After rewritting the function in your locale codePool, you can add you new variable like this:

```
public function sendNewOrderEmail()
{
/*.
  .
  . there is some Magento code here*/

    // it's here where you have to add a variable
    $myValue = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($this->getMyValue()); // for exemple
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
      'order'         => $this,
      'billing'       => $this->getBillingAddress(),
      'payment_html'  => $paymentBlockHtml,
      'new_variable'  => $myValue // your new param here (variable)
   ));
   /*Rest of the code remains the same*/
 }
```

Now you can get your variable in the this template email like this: `{{var new_variable}}`

**Solution 2: (phtml)**

You add your variable in some phtml that you get it in the email template like this:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='page/html/email/var1.phtml' order=$order}}
```

And you add your variable value in this phtml like this:

```
<?php 
 $customer_id = 10;
 $myValue = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
 echo $myValue->getMyValue() ; 
?> // for exemple
```

Comment: I need to separate the shipping  &  Billing Address Variables but I don't know which files to use or Module  >> I will be grateful if you help me to do it @Prince